# Нет роута с именем products.show

Tags: laravel5

Сделал роуты ресурсов в ларавел, вот так

```
Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
```

Но метода show с именем products.show, при попытке его вызвать нет, что мне делать?

Comment: `php artisan route:list` показывает роут?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E_K совершенно прав! Несмотря на то что роут ресурсов, как указанно в документации:

```
(https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/controllers#%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81)
```

к LARAVEL5 (указанно в вашем вопросе) с именем products.show для вашего примера должен быть, наилучшим решением в даннй ситуации будет просмотреть при помощи команды:

```
php artisan route:list
```

список доступных роутов и если искомого роута в нем нет, то добавить его вручную, вот так:

```
Route::get('/products/{product}', 'ProductController@show')->name('products.show');
```

И если я ответил на ваш вопрос, надеюсь вы примите его!)